# Nginx Instances which are Launching in Public subnet with public IP in VPC but unable to connect to Network

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, aws-cloudformation

Our AWS instances are created in a `public subnet` availability zone and are **not able to connect to the internet and SSH**. So all the resources are created on the public subnet and one AZ.

I have developed CF nginx template with single VPC and two public subnets, butsecond public subnet instances are unable to connect network and SSH even though I'm giving public IP of the instance in the browser it is not working.

The main issue is instances which are launching in the second public subnet are unable to connect internet system logs are:

- Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the
  problem
- Reconfigure the base URL/etc.
- Disable the repository, so yum won't use it by default

Comment: Can you clarify your question? It helps to use punctuation ;)

Comment: I have developed CF nginx template with single VPC and two public subnets, after launching the stack instances are creating in both public subnets but second public subnet instances are unable to connect network and SSH even though I'm giving public IP of the instance in the browser it is not working.The main issue is instances which are launching in the second public subnet are unable to connect internet system logs are 1) Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem2)Reconfigure the base URL/etc.3)Disable the repository, so yum won't use it by default.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the scenario generally in order to enable access to or from the Internet for instances in a VPC subnet, you must do the following:

- Attach an Internet gateway to your VPC.
- Ensure that your subnet's route table points to the Internet gateway.
- Ensure that instances in your subnet have a globally unique IP
  address (public IPv4 address, Elastic IP address, or IPv6 address).
- Ensure that your network access control and security group rules
  allow the relevant traffic to flow to and from your instance.

To use an Internet gateway, your subnet's route table must contain a route that directs Internet-bound traffic to the Internet gateway. You can scope the route to all destinations not explicitly known to the route table (0.0.0.0/0 for IPv4 or ::/0 for IPv6).

Kindly Refer this [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html#Add_IGW_Routing) and see what you are missing , as you must have skipped one of the above mentioned things.

Comment: Also, if using ACLs to control the traffic, remember to allow outbound to all ephemeral ports (1025-65535)